# Laravel Authentication - getting email attribute from different tables

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-api

I'm trying to authenticate when a user login he can login using username or email but the problem I'm facing is that the main table user it has only the username and the ucode of the different users like admin, teacher, student. The  email attribute is in the table admin, teacher and student. How to get the email and authenticate it?

Comment: kindly show your table and model relationship

Comment: the main table user has username password usercode(is a foreign key)  which is the primary key of three user tables(teacher,student,admin) , in these tables the email is there, i need to authenticate it.

Comment: Because the user can login using his username or email